# ActionBarCompat and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've developed an app with fragment and actionbar but only when I've finished, I've discovered that not works on android version < 3.0! Now, I've read about the support.v7 and ActionBarCompat but I've those errors in logcat:

```
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.<init>(PduPersister.java:288)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.getPduPersister(PduPersister.java:296)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:224)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:621)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-07 10:52:15.160: E/StrictMode(873):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

How can I solve?

UPDATE:
This is a piece of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
        ViewPager mViewPager;
        int mCurCheckPosition;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

            mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            Log.d("1","ok");

            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Log.d("1","ok"); isn't in my logacat

Comment: Show some of the code your using. You are probably using input/output buffers and never close them or release them.

Comment: Now I've updated my post